# How to use CameraX together with Camera2 API?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am currently trying to enable macro mode in Android using the CameraX API. As CameraX seems not to support macro focus mode, I want to make use of Camera2.

Is there a possibility to use Camera2 in order to enable macro for CameraX?

Thanks for any help.